# Programming Assignment Involving Input and Output to .dat file

Tags: java, file, input, output, createfile

This an assignment for this week in my programming class. I know what direction I need to go in, but some of the specific details have me confused.

```
My Credit Card Company has a file that called “BeginningBalance.dat” which 
contains the following information:
Customer number->integer
Beginning Balance->double
Purchases->double
Payments->double
The company charges 1% of the beginning balance for finance charges.
Write a Java program that does the following:
Read in the file, calculates the finance charge per customer
Display all information to the monitor including finance charge and 
outstanding balance • Creates an output file called “NewBalance.dat” that 
contains customer number and new balance.
```

So I figure that I need to create the beginning file, read it into Java, pass that data into an array and display it, calculate the new data and output it to a new file. I'm just not sure how I should start. Anything would help, thanks so much.

Comment: one approach is by writing code

Comment: @MartinČuka thanks for this helpful bit of information. Glad you're so welcoming.

Comment: you are welcome :-)

Comment: Try using a `DataInputStream` to read the .dat file.

Comment: I would suggest using `Scanner` to read the .dat file